# Можно ли изменить источник ввод cin

Tags: c++, ввод, cin

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;



int fn() {

    int n;
    cin >> n

    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли как-то подать в поток ввода данные для записи в переменную n не с клавиатуры, и ничего не изменять в fn? Может можно как-то записать данные в буфер, чтобы потом с помощью cin их считать?
Хочу сделать программу для тестирования произвольных функций.

Comment: Просто пишите функции, принимающие `std::istream&` в качестве аргумента. Тогда можно передавать в них как `std::cin`, так и `std::ifstream` или `std::string_stream`. Ну или можно использовать цепочки bash при запуске программы, например, `$ echo "42" | my_app`

Comment: А кто мешает писать вот так в консоли `cat filename.txt | ./main` и получится что как будто читает с файла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите изменить буфер `std::cin`. Да, но только не забывать потом вернуть старый.

```
std::ifstream in("some_file");
//установим новый буфер, очистим буфер и вернем старый
std::streambuf* buf = cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());
//теперь cin читает из буфера файлового потока
fn();
//установим старый
cin.rdbuf(buf);
```

Comment: Стоило, наверное, написать  шаблон функции, дабы иметь обобщенную функцию.